# How to append a tuple to an array object in Swift code?

Tags: swift, xcode6

I searched google, but i cant find a way to append new element to array object in Swift.
The error code "Missing arguments fot parameter "name" in call" is come up.
My code is followed.

```
var arrayObj: [(id: Int, name: String)] = []
var idInt: Int = 1
var nameString: String = "hoge"
arrayObj.append((        // ----> "Missing arguments fot parameter "name" in call"
    id: idInt,
    name: nameString
))
```

if you know any solution, I'd be very glad.
Thanks.

Comment: If you use a `typealias` it works.  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just assign the tuple to a temp variable:

```
let tuple = (        
    id: idInt,
    name: nameString
)

arrayObj.append(tuple)
```

Not sure why it doesn't work that way - just checked on a function, like this:

```
var array:  [(param1: Int, param2: String)] = []

func test(x: (param1: Int, param2: String)) {
    println(x)
}

test((param1: 2, param2: "Test"))
array.append((param1: 2, param2: "Test"))
```

Result: the function works, the array method doesn't.

**Update**: Tried this code in a playground:

```
struct Test<T> {
    func doSomething(param: T) {
        println(param)
    }
}

var test = Test<(param1: Int, param2: String)>()
let tuple = (param1: 2, param2: "Test")
test.doSomething(tuple)
test.doSomething((param1: 2, param2: "Test"))
```

Result: it works when passing the `tuple` variable to `doSomething` - using the literal tuple instead doesn't, although the compiler message is different:

```
'((param1: Int, param2: String)) ->()' does not have a member named 'doSomething'
```

Apparently passing a literal tuple to a method of a generic class (where the tuple is the generic type) is not correctly handled by the compiler.

**Update #2**: I repeated the test on a non-generic class, but using a generic method, and in this case it worked:

```
struct Test {
    func doSomething<T>(param: T) {
        println(param)
    }
}

var test = Test()
let tuple = (param1: 2, param2: "Test")
test.doSomething(tuple)
test.doSomething((param1: 2, param2: "Test"))
```

So it's definitely a problem related to generic classes only.

Comment: See updated answer - no solution, but it looks like it's a compiler problem

Comment: This is interesting analysis, Antonio.  It certainly seems like a compiler problem.

Comment: Wow, great investigative work -- `array.append((param1: 2, param2: "Test"))` has never worked; it seems like you've figured out why.

Comment: @NateCook thanks - actually I figured out under which conditions it happens, but not why... :)

Comment: Well, the "why" is that there's a bug in the compiler. :) But knowing that it affects all generic types is probably important for the development team to track the issue down. I'd only ever seen the error in relation to array.append().

Comment: Did one more test with generic method of non-generic class, and it worked. See updated answer.

Comment: Wow. This is a pretty big bug to go unfixed for this long… unfortunately assigning to a temp variable didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 10):

More fun workarounds:

```
arrayObj += [(id: idInt, name: nameString)]
```

and

```
arrayObj.append([(id: idInt, name: nameString)][0])
```

---

Curiously, this works if you use a `typealias`:

```
typealias MyData = (id: Int, name: String)

var arrayObj: [MyData] = []
var idInt: Int = 1
var nameString: String = "hoge"

arrayObj.append((id: idInt, name: nameString))
```

**EDIT:**

One more workaround:

```
arrayObj.insert((id: idInt, name: nameString), atIndex:index)
```

Comment: +1 for your 2nd solution - I like it and solves the problem, although the question is still unanswered - suspect a compiler bug

Answer (score 7):

I just want to clear some things up:

If you have an **array of tuples with named elements**, just like in the answer, you can use the syntax described below to add elements to the array:

```
arrayObj.append(id: 1, name: "TestName")
```

If you have an **array of tuples with not named elements**, like this:

```
var arrayObj: [(Int, String)] = []
```

use this:

```
arrayObj.append(1, "TestName")
```

If you created a **typealias** for you **tuple**, you can add elements to the list with the tuple syntax:

```
typealias MyTuple = (Int, String)
var arrayObj: [MyTuple] = []

arrayObj.append((1, "TestName"))
```