# Passing tuple to AFNetworkingRequestManger.GET in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, tuples, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I have bridged AFNetworking 2.5 to work with my Swift project.

I have the following function:

```
internal func performAction(var httpMethod: String, var url : String, headers: Dictionary<String, String>?, params: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>?, successClosure: ((operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation, responseObject: AnyObject?) -> ())?, failureClosure: ((operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation, error: NSError) -> ())?) {
        let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()            

        let internalSuccessClosure = { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject: AnyObject!) -> Void in
            if let succ = successClosure {
                succ(operation: operation, responseObject: responseObject)
            }
        }

        let internalFailureClosure = { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
            if let fail = failureClosure {
                fail(operation: operation, error: error)
            }
        }

        var methodParams = (url, params, internalSuccessClosure, internalFailureClosure)

        if httpMethod == HTTP_METHOD_GET {
            manager.GET(methodParams)
        } else if httpMethod == HTTP_METHOD_POST {
            manager.POST(methodParams)
        }
    }
```

The Swift compiler is complaining: `Missing argument for parameter 'parameters' in call` for both `manager.GET(methodParams)` and `manager.POST(methodParams)`

The following call to manager.GET() compiles as expected:

```
manager.GET(url,
            parameters: params,
            success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, responseObject: AnyObject!) in
                    if let succ = successClosure {
                        succ(operation: operation, responseObject: responseObject)
                    }
                },
            failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!, error: NSError!) in
                    if let fail = failureClosure {
                        fail(operation: operation, error: error)
                    }
            })
```

I've tried basic examples of passing a tuple for multiple argument parameters, and it has worked, so I am unsure why I am having issues here.

I tried this in Playground, and it works as expected:

```
func addTwoNumbers(x: Int, y: Int) -> Int {
    return x + y
}

let twoNumbers = (1,2)

addTwoNumbers(twoNumbers)
```

I have checked out: https://medium.com/swift-programming/facets-of-swift-part-4-functions-3cce9d9bba4 and [How to append a tuple to an array object in Swift code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26076227/how-to-append-a-tuple-to-an-array-object-in-swift-code) but they haven't been able to help me solve the problem.

Comment: The problem with this approach is you don’t get as much help from Xcode/the compiler where you have a type error.  Are you sure some of the arguments to the closure expressions shouldn’t take an optionals e.g. `NSError?` rather than an `NSError`  (that sentence should end in ? but I shall not put one there to avoid confusion :)

Comment: Are you positive that you can use the tuple of the same size as the required parameters for bridged Objective-C code? I haven't tried it myself, but I wouldn't be surprised if that was only available for Swift native code. As such, could you try using the [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) library?

Comment: @AndrewMonshizadeh An excellent suggestion! I didn't know that existed.... however looking at the documentation, it suggests using AFNetworking for "UIKit extensions, such as asynchronously loading images to UIImageView," which is functionality I need.

Comment: @noilly Yeah, that is certainly a valid case to use the bridged AFNetworking. But, like the documentation also says, they can live in harmony. So maybe you can rewrite this particular method in terms of Alamofire and use the AFNetworking UIKit extensions only where necessary? Just a thought.

Comment: @AndrewMonshizadeh That's true, and I think in the short term I'm going to go with Alamofire so I'm working with something built specifically for Swift; as I suspect tat you might be right about passing a tuple to Obj-C code. However, it would be awesome if someone could confirm that this is the real issue, or if there is another issue at hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is not possible to pass a tuple as parameter values to objective-c code.