# Tuple containing an array (and assigned as variable) not working?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create an array of tuples in swift where each tuple contains a (1)letter and (2)array of custom objects, but when I try to append it throws the error 'Int' is not convertible to 'T'.

Here is the simplified code:

```
    var tuples : [(letter : Character , objects : [myObject])] = []
    //this works
    tuples.append(letter:"test".firstChar(), objects: [myObject(), myObject()])
    //gives error =>  'Int' is not convertable to 'T' on the append function
    var arrayOfObjects : [myObject] = []
    tuples.append(letter:"test".firstChar(), objects: arrayOfObjects)
```

Comment: Strange!  `tuples.append(letter: "test".firstChar(), objects: arrayOfObjects as [myObject])` works. Also if you make arrayOfObjects constant works as well. Don't know why

Comment: Yeah there are still some small bugs with tuples, hope this gets fixed with possible Swift 1.3 in a few days :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to append a tuple to an array object in Swift code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26076227/how-to-append-a-tuple-to-an-array-object-in-swift-code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
let arrayOfObjects : [myObject] = []
tuples.append(letter:"t", objects: arrayOfObjects)
```

As you can see, `arrayOfObjects` is a constant. The problem here might stem from the fact that `append` expects a constant parameter `T`, while you are passing a tuple containing a `var`.
IMHO this is what makes `append` goes a little crazy, and the compiler gives a crazier error description ;-)

Comment: Confirmed, this works! :         var arrayOfObjects : [myObject] = []
        let gain = arrayOfObjects
        tuples.append(letter:"test".firstChar(), objects: gain)

Comment: Why does this work then `var array :[Int] = [] var a = 1 array.append(a)` ? And how to do know that append expect constant ?

Comment: With _constant_ I meant constant as a _whole_ and in a _consistent_ way. I was just wondering what could be the cause of what is probably a bug. AFAIK tuples are value type, so `append` needs to _copy_ it. The problem could arise since here the passed tuple is, in part, marked as _mutable_ (`var`).

Comment: The _copy on change_ mechanism might also be involved in the problem above. Anyway generally speaking, `let` will save you a lot of headaches ;-)

Comment: Yes indeed let saved the day :) but still would be nice if Apple solves this, but not a show stopper anymore